# Android list selection

Tags: android, android-listview

How to get selected list item from list view in center of the screen irrespective of previous selected items in expandable list view

Comment: Not getting what you want to post some code and clear your question.

Comment: have you tried this example....http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Comment: i have expandable list view it consists of 10 items.Whenever user selects the last item it is expanding but not getting focus.The requirement is if user selects the last item ,that item should be in middle of screen irrespective of other items.